# Prettier is not formatting my Styled Components code

Tags: reactjs, formatting, eslint, styled-components, prettier

I'm using Prettier, Eslint and Styled components in my project. The eslint rules are working so far. I don't know why, but Prettier is not formatting the styled components code.

Let me show you the example code that I am trying to fix:

This is the original code:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
font-size: 1.15em;
margin: 0;
}
`;
```

This is the code that I am expecting to get after formatting through Prettier and Eslint (but I am not) :

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
        font-size: 1.15em;
        margin: 0;
    }
`;
```

My eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "next/core-web-vitals",
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "project": "tsconfig.json",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin", "react", "prettier"],
    "rules": {
        "react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "no-shadow": "off"
    },
    "ignorePatterns": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

My .prettierrc:

```
{
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "printWidth": 120,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "useTabs": false
}
```

Any modification or recommendation will be more than welcome. So is there any way to solve this problem correctly? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I read [here](https://github.com/styled-components/vscode-styled-components/issues/175) that this seems to be a code editor formatting problem. I found 4 possible solutions.

1. Configure the code editors extensions correctly (not sure what the issue is in this/your case though)
2. Press Opt+Shift+F and pick a code editor
3. Do a workaround as suggested in the github link above, where you do the following:

```
import * as styled from 'styled-components';

export default styled.createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  code {
    font-family: comic-sans-ms; 
  }
`;
```

4. Another workaround:

```
const xyz = css`
  body {
    background: red;
  }
`;
/* ↑ gets formatted by Prettier */

createGlobalStyle`
  ${xyz}
`;
```